# Salesforce mobile scrolling issues with input fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-web-components, mobile, lightning-inputfield

I've been trying to adjust a record form to mobile version of salesforce. However, I'm having issues with scrolling. When I try to scroll down for the first time after page refresh, the screen stops at the first input field below the view and goes (bounces?) back up. Wrapping it in  doesn't change anything. The problem doesn't exist with lightning:input, it appears only with lightning:inputField.

The code I'm trying to run:

```xml
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride, lightning:hasPageReference">
    <ui:scrollerWrapper >
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Account" recordTypeId="{!v.pageReference.state.recordTypeId}">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>
</aura:component>
```

The field is the same in all inputs just for demonstration. It works the same if the fields are different.

I have tried it in LWC too, same result. I have checked both on PC (chrome toggle device toolbar) and the mobile app, both give the same results.

A demonstration of what happens can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwzyN.jpg

I need help with fixing this "bouncing" issue.

Comment: Same here l. Seems to be an issue with the core component recordeditform (they are probably wrapping the lwc cmp with and aura container). I'm actually experiencing it with the record view form as well. I tend to think that anything more the a few fields causes this which what is needed for anything beyond demoware.  Lmk if u come up with a hack. Working on some myself as well